# unable to edit R.java Android using Eclipse

Tags: android-layout, r.java-file

I am new to Android. Well the problem I am facing is that I have two layouts. One is main.xml and another that I made was relative_layout.xml.

I did not give it an @+id/ to this layout so the default id was relative_layout01.xml but when I gave this an id the old one still remain in my R.java and when I edit R.java it again generated the old version of file.

I want to delete relative_layout01.xml reference as it does not exists as I have given a name to my layout.

Attaching an image for reference.[image]

Comment: ZOOM TO IMAGE: if you are using Google Chrome then right click on image and press "open image in new tab" other wise right click and press "copy shortcut" then open new tab and press paste then enter to Zoom the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.java should be refreshed automatically.

Maybe you still have some references to it in your code (setContentView(R.relative...) or you still have it as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Sorry for the noobish answer. Just my 2 cents..

Answer (score 0):

Delete import android.R, and R.java completely, rebuild and it would be fine